# How to create object for a struct in golang

Tags: go, struct

*File1.go*

```
Package abc

type ECA struct {
    *CA
    obcKey          []byte
    obcPriv, obcPub []byte
    gRPCServer      *grpc.Server
}


type ECAP struct {
    eca *ECA
}


func (ecap *ECAP) ReadCACertificate(ctx context.Context, in *pb.Empty) (*pb.Cert, error) {
    Trace.Println("gRPC ECAP:ReadCACertificate")

    return &pb.Cert{Cert: ecap.eca.raw}, nil
}
```

*File2.go*

```
package main

import "abc"

var ecap abc.ECAP //creating instance

func main() {
    err = ecap.ReadCACertificate(floo,floo)
}
```

I am a newbie. I want to create instance of ECAP struct and call ReadCACertificate method. Right now i am creating like this "var ecap abc.ECAP //creating instance" which is giving "nil" and nil pointer error.

Can anyone help how to call the ReadCACertificate method in efficient way.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Your example is incomplete, but basically you need to initialize your struct, since it has pointers, and default pointer value is nil.

```
var ecap := ECAP{new(ECA)}
```

Comment: I am importing package "abc" into another package "main". If you see the struct "ECAP" has one field "eca" which is un-exported field in package "abc".

If i tried to create instance for ECAP struct i am getting error **"implicit assignment of unexported field 'eca' in abc.ECAP literal"**

Comment: If you stick with the packages, then use also abc.ECA

Comment: **ecap := abc.ECAP{new(abc.ECA)}** is giving error "implicit assignment of unexported field 'eca' in abc.ECAP literal" as eca is un-exported field in ECA struct.

Answer (score 0):

You need to import the second file from your $GOPATH.  And your function return 2 values, not just an error.

```
package main


import (
     "$RELATIVE_PATH_FROM_GOPATH/abc"
)


var ecap := ECAP{new(ECA)} //initialize your struct, since it has pointers

func main() {
    cert, err = ecap.ReadCACertificate(floo,floo)
}
```

## File 1

```
type ECAP struct {
    Eca *ECA //uppercase make field be exported
}
```

Comment: two files are in 2 different packages.

Comment: @balakrishna how about now?
added Alexey Soshin tip as well

Comment: Thanks for the reply @CESCO. 

ecap := abc.ECAP{new(abc.ECA)} is giving error "implicit assignment of unexported field 'eca' in abc.ECAP literal" as eca is un-exported field in ECA struct.

Comment: Unfortunately i should not touch the package "abc". Is there any way that i can do without changing to exported field ?